# How to wait till other function is finished in javascript using wait / async?

Tags: javascript

I have below functions. I am trying to read csv file row by row and trying to get account details at the same time like below.

```
async function Upload() {
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
            if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        var csv = e.target.result;
                        var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv);                    
                        var investorsBalance = "";
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            investorsBalance = await getAccountDetailsInvestor(data[i].investor_id,data[i].asset_code).then(ret_val => {
                                alert("ret_val :"+ret_val);
                                investorsBalance = ret_val;
                            })
                            alert("investorsBalance :"+investorsBalance)                                                    
                        }                   
                    }
                    reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);                                                             
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
            }                   
        }

async function getAccountDetailsInvestor(investorId,assetCode){
    var investorsBalance = "";
    console.log("getAccountDetails :"+investorId);
    $("#overlay").show();
    var accountKeys = "";
    var userLoadAccount = "";
    userLoadAccount = await server.loadAccount(investorId);
    var data = userLoadAccount.balances;            
    var count = 1;
    var tempData = "";                      
    data.forEach(function(obj){
        var res = (obj.asset_type =="native");
        if(!res){
            if(obj.asset_code == assetCode){
                investorsBalance = obj.balance
            }
        }
    })          
    $("#overlay").hide();   
    return investorsBalance;
}
```

I am getting below errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I want to wait till getAccountDetailsInvestor() function completes. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to mark the `reader.onload  = async function (e)...` callback function as async

Comment: Can you please specify in details if possible? Do I need to write like this reader.onload = function async (e) {}

Comment: Will still not work correctly with async, without actually changing the .then() handler.

Comment: although your main function Upload is marked as async, the enclosing function ```reader.onload``` is not marked as async. The await keyword is only valid inside async functions. If you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a SyntaxError.

Comment: @DanStarns That's the problem. With your change and none other, there is a `await func().then()` in the code. Check the question.

Comment: sorry i must be mistaken here? because the question remains. "I want to wait till getAccountDetailsInvestor() function completes. How to do it?" I just checked MDNS [defenition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) of async await and its clear that "async await pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution". Using the .then() approach you cant guarantee the execution time of the promise.

Comment: Hi I tried reader.onload  = async function (e) {} and removed async from function declaration & await from call to getAccountDetailsInvestor function but I am getting promise object as response in investorBalance variable..like Promise {<pending>}

Comment: @DeveloperDesk you still need to await getAccountDetailsInvestor

Comment: @DanStarns As I said, look in the code of the question. You will see, that there is a `await.getAccountDetailsInvestor().then()` which is obviously wrong. Just by adding async it will not make this code good. If you cant figure out what I mean, just look at my answer.

Comment: @MauriceNino your answer says 1 of two things, the same as mine... & "Handle the async function without await like so" in my opinion this is false perspective because by using .then() you cannot guarantee when the callback will execute. If you use .then in this code...  ```alert("investorsBalance :"+investorsBalance)``` will execute before ```getAccountDetailsInvestor.then()``` has completed.

Comment: These are two options to solve the problem. The first one is like yours, but note the second step that is missing in your answer. It is crucial and without it, your answer is incomplete. @DanStarns

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays within this part:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var csv = e.target.result;
    var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv);                    
    var investorsBalance = "";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        // You cant use await in a non-async function
        // You also cant use await
        investorsBalance = await getAccountDetailsInvestor(data[i].investor_id,data[i].asset_code)
        // And .then() in the same statement
        .then(ret_val => {
            alert("ret_val :"+ret_val);
            investorsBalance = ret_val;
        })
        alert("investorsBalance :"+investorsBalance)                                                    
    }                   
}
```

You have two options.

### 1) Make the `onload` function async like so:

```
reader.onload = async function(e) {
   // ... your code           
}
```

And remove the `.then()` handler (because `await` is your `then()` and `try/catch` is your `catch()` in async functions):

```
investorsBalance = await getAccountDetailsInvestor(data[i].investor_id,data[i].asset_code)

// No need for .then() - just use the returned variable
alert("ret_val :" + investorsBalance); 
investorsBalance = investorsBalance ;
alert("investorsBalance :"+investorsBalance)
```

### 2) Handle the async function without `await` like so:

```
// No need for await - just handle it with the callback function then()
investorsBalance = getAccountDetailsInvestor(data[i].investor_id,data[i].asset_code)
.then(ret_val => {
   alert("ret_val :" + ret_val);
   investorsBalance = ret_val;
   alert("investorsBalance :"+investorsBalance)  
})
```